# In The Prisoner of Azkaban movie, what wolf howled in the distance, drawing werewolf Lupin away?

Tags: harry-potter

Lupin was getting the best of Sirius, and if not for the interruption would most probably have killed him.  What wolf would have compelled Lupin to leave the fight and go to him/her?

Comment: Didn't Hermione howl?

Answer (score 7):

Later in the movie this is clearly shown to be future Hermione imitating a wolf howl. When Harry and Hermione go back in time they see the fight from afar and Hermione then imitates the wolf call, explaining to Harry that she was saving his (past self's) life. Presumably, she figured out that it must have been her future self all along, much like Harry figured out that it had been his future self that cast the Patronus.

Here is the relevant clip:

Answer (score 5):

If I remember properly, it was not actually a wolf. It was Hermione, who imitated the howl of a female wolf, and more precisely a female wolf asking for male company, in order to save Sirius.

Comment: Did Hermione ever actually say what kind of call she was imitating? From what I remember she just howled, and then they ran away.

Comment: She was taking a terrible risk, had Lupin (as a werewolf) found her he'd kill her for sure. She just expected Lupin to go straight to the place she called from, thinking a female wolf would stay put, while Hermione ran away as fast as she could.

Comment: No, she did not say what kind of call she imitated. I'm just reasoning. What **kind** of call was most likely to attract Lupin with enough strength for him to abandon a fight ?

Comment: That's just speculation on your part. I find highly improbable that Hermione knows exactly how to imitate the howl of a needy female wolf.

Comment: Yes, this point is speculation. What she did was imitate the howl she heard on her "own" time, before howling in her future-coming-back in time. But look at Lupin's reaction. Why was he suddenly so eager to abandon the fight to run in the direction of the howl ?

Comment: This is a standard paradox in time travel, that is **not** usually considered as a severe one. When some time traveller remembers seeing/hearing in her/his own past something that only (s)he could have done, and does it to **avoid** a time paradox, who is it who **invented** the details of that action ? Not the old self, who just observed the result, not the future self who just imitated what (s)he observed.